# How can I pull data from my entity with a foreach loop to use it in a formBuilder?

Tags: forms, symfony, foreach, controller

I am using the Formbuilder in my Controller in Symfony 4:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($item)
      ->add('id', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
      ->add('username', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
      ->add('email', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
      ->add('is_active', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
      ->add('password', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
```

I created those fields that are in my entity manually. What I want to do now is create this fields automatically with a loop. So this is my approach:

```
  $form = $this->createFormBuilder($item)
      foreach ($item as $field) {
          ->add($field, TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
      }
```

But I get the error message:

> syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)

Comment: As @fiskolin stated, the first error to fix is very simple, just add a semicolon to the end of line 1 of your posted code. Then see if the rest works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot chain methods that way, since you missed a `semicolon` before `foreach`.

First, you need to define your `formBuilder` instance using:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($item); // (assuming `$item` is defined).
```

Then, you could populate it in `foreach` loop:

```
$fields = array("id", "username", "email", "is_active", "password");
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $form->add($field, TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')));
}
```

Then, your `$form` will contains all fields populated.

Comment: But this means, I have to write these fields again manually `array("id", "username", "email", "is_active", "password");` I need that the fields are automatically detected because I want to use the function for many different entities

Comment: You need to pass those fields in some way (by a function parameter or even manually). Btw, what you mean by `I need that the fields are automatically detected`?

Comment: This means that if I have 1000 fields in my entity I cannot write `$fields = array("one", "two", "three", ... "thousand");` manually. This would take me a year. So the array $fields has to be created from the entity fields. There must be a way to do that

Comment: maybe something like this would work? `$fields = $entityManager->getClassMetadata->getFieldForColumn($item);`

Comment: What is your `$item` attribute? What it takes?

Comment: `$item = new $EntityName(); $item= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository($EntityName)->find($id);`

Comment: This is the variable $item: `object(App\Entity\Members)#4316 (6) {
  ["id":"App\Entity\Members":private]=>
  int(1)
  ["username":"App\Entity\Members":private]=>
  string(5) "123"
  ["plainPassword":"App\Entity\Members":private]=>
  NULL
  ["password":"App\Entity\Members":private]=>
  string(60) "123"
  ["email":"App\Entity\Members":private]=>
  string(17) "123@123.com"
  ["isActive":"App\Entity\Members":private]=>
  bool(true)
}`

Comment: Please improve issue details on question itself so I can help you trough this.